# Remove backbone query string

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript

I have a Backbone application and I would like to remove the query string from parameters passed to the function.

These are some of the routes:

```
routes:
    '': 'home'
    'categories/:id/:sid(/)': 'subcategories'
    'categories/:id(/)': 'categories'
```

Now, in `categories` (or `subcategories`) function, the last parameter also includes the query string, which I don't want.
I have tried the folowing:

- 'categories/:id([\?]{1}:q)': 'categories'
- 'categories/:id([\?]{0,1}:q)': 'categories'
- 'categories/:id([\?]?:q)': 'categories'

but for an url like `categories/1?page=2`, `:id` is `1?page=2`.

How can I remove what follows `?` ?

I am aware of [backbone-query-string](https://github.com/kr1zmo/backbone-query-string), but I don't want to use it.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is one way to handle this.
If you visit the link(*categories/1?page=2* or *categories/1*),

Write router like this:

```
'categories/:id\?:page' : 'categories'

'categories/:id' : 'categories'

categories: function(id){}
```

The **id** parameter will be the '1', and the **page** will be the 'page=2', but you can deprecate it.

**Please notice the sequence of two routers**